# Singleton created twice

Tags: laravel, singleton, laravel-5.4, global-scope

In Laravel 5.4 I have registered a Service Provider that creates a singleton to my Context class which holds application context.

**ContextServiceProvider**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App;

class ContextServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // Set-up application context
        $context = app('context');
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('context', function ($app) {
            return new App\Context();
        });

    }
}
```

Then I create a Eloquent model with a global scope.

**Model Media**

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Scopes\SchoolScope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Media extends Model
{    
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new SchoolScope());
    }    
}
```

Now when I access the Context singleton in the scope SchoolScope, the singleton is created **twice**!

**SchoolScope**

```
namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

use App\Models\School;

class SchoolScope implements Scope
{
    protected $school;

    public function __construct()
    {        
        $this->school = app('context')->school;
    }

    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {        
        $builder->where('school_id', '=', $this->school->id);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why the singleton is created twice?

Comment: remove it from `boot` method of service provider

Comment: Thanks @omadonex, I tried, but it makes no difference.

Comment: are you testing that you receives two different instances of an object?

Comment: Yes, it's going twice through the constructor of the Context class.